# Pointer cannot be compared to integer?

Tags: c

This is a part of a project that I'm working on ... and I keep getting an error saying pointer and integer cannot be compared; any suggestions?

```
//variable declaration//
int i=0;

bool validatePlaneClass(char* src)
{
     //declare variable//
     int c=0;
     //declare local array //
     char class1[9]= "airplane";
     char class2[11]= "helicopter";
     char class3[4]= "jet";
     char class4[7]= "glider";

  if(*src != class1)
  {    
        printf("You have entered an incorrect class!!");
  }
  else
  {  
  if(*src != class2)
     {
          printf("You have entered an incorrect class!!");
     }
     else
     {
     if(*src != class3)
     {
         printf("You have entered an incorrect class!!");
     }
     else
     {
     if(*src != class4)
     {
         printf("You have entered an incorrect class!!");
     }
     else
     {
     }
     }
     }
  }/*end if else*/

}/*end function*/
```

Comment: Don't compare integers and pointers?

Comment: You need `strcmp` in `string.h`.

Comment: Also, you commented out the code and it's difficult to read in here:(

Comment: `*src` is the first character in the argument string; it is converted to an integer.  That isn't what you want.

Comment: Please learn how to indent C.  Note that standard C style uses `if (cond1) { …stmt1… } else if (cond2) { …stmt2… }` rather than `if (cond1) { …stmt1… } else { if (cond2) { …stmt2… } }` (which has an extra pair of braces around the second `if`, and leads to code marching off the RHS of the display).

Comment: This is an unreadable mess.

Comment: Any reason you fix the sizes of the arrays and don't let the compiler do it? Error-prone. Not to mention this is done for each call. Use `static const` arrays or the literals directly or pointers to the literals.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use strcmp function if you want to compare char strings. https://10hash.com/c/string/#idm45440463474848 will help.

Comment: Edited pointers to strings which is what I meant.